# Flutter issue: 'ChipsInputState' is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm currently learning Flutter using Android Studio but I can't figure this issue help pls thank you :(

> Compiler message:
>   ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_chips_input-1.3.1/lib/src/chips_input.dart:42:7:
>   Error: The non-abstract class 'ChipsInputState' is missing
>   implementations for these members:
>    - TextInputClient.connectionClosed Try to either
>    - provide an implementation,
>    - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
>    - mark the class as abstract, or
>    - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
>
> class ChipsInputState extends State>
>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:658:8:
>   Context: 'TextInputClient.connectionClosed' is defined here.   void
>   connectionClosed();
>          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null build failed.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script '/Users/clyde/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'
>     line: 780
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
>   > Process 'command '/Users/clyde/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 18s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [Flutter Form Builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder), you can manually update the flutter_chips_input library to the latest version because the Flutter form builder uses an old version.

This issue was discussed in the Flutter GitHub repository Issues section [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57275).

Adding the below dependency manually to the `pubspec.yaml` file solved the problem for me:

```
flutter_chips_input: ^1.9.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are on dev or master channel (at least that is the cause in my case)...you can switch to beta or stable to get rid of the error:

```
flutter channel beta|stable
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same problem and not sure how that was fixed.
I have tried the following things

1. Check Flutter Doctor and fix if you have any errors
2. Try Flutter clean
3. Delete pubspec.lock file and run flutter pub get or flutter pub upgrade

I Hope, that may help you guys.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me

- Look for packages in your `pubspec.yaml` file that depend on the `chips_input` package, e.g. `form_builder` and make sure it's the latest version.
- Upgrade all packages in `pubspec.yaml` file to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stack with the same error. I've searched and tried everything and nothing works.

Based on searching, the issues may have been caused by using flutter_form_builder package on an incompatible version of flutter SDK.

What works for me (Windows user):

- Tried switching to master|stable version
- Deleted all flutter and pub temp directories/folders:
  Navigate to C:/Users/(Current User)/AppData/Local/Temp/ and delete all directories/folders having
     *flutter_tool.xxx*, *native-platformxxx*, and *pubxxx*
- Installed the latest version of Flutter SDK.

  https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/windows/flutter_windows_1.17.3-stable.zip
- Tried Flutter clean
- Deleted pubspec.lock file and run flutter pub get or flutter pub upgrade

Upon building my project, another issue pop-up, NDK version not found. Instead of downloading the required NDK, I removed/renamed the NDK directory/folder from my Android SDK directory/folder.

Hope this steps helps.